# Calling ng-click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, button

I need to go way back on a site that has a "Load more" button. I'm going to have to press it like 100 times and have to scroll down to bottom of page each time to click it.

Is there some way to call the function by pasting som Javascript in the Chrome console?

```
<button class="button-dark button-icon--next button-right" ng-hide="vm.fetchingMoreData" ng-if="vm.pageNo  <= vm.numberOfTransactions" ng-click="vm.showMoreTransactions()" ng-disabled="vm.fetchingMoreData" ng-bind="'see_more' | i18n">Show more</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can use

```
element.click()
```

after selecting the button to click on a button programmatically
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

In your case, you can also call that function of ng-click in js i.e

```
vm.showMoreTransactions()
```

directly in your script

Comment: I get an error when pasting it into console

vm.showMoreTransactions()
VM452:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: vm is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1